# How to append non-literals type to strings in C++ / Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

My Code:

```
QSqlQuery myqry;

    myqry.prepare( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Item (ItemCat VARCHAR(20), ItemId VARCHAR(7) UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, ItemName VARCHAR(30), ItemBrand VARCHAR(20), ItemModel VARCHAR(10), ItemQuantity INTEGER, ItemPrice DOUBLE)" );

    if( !myqry.exec() )
        qDebug() << myqry.lastError();
    else
        qDebug() << "Table created!";

    QString category, id, name, brand, model, quantity, price;

    myqry.prepare( "INSERT INTO Item (ItemCat, ItemId, ItemName, ItemBrand, ItemModel, ItemQuantity, ItemPrice) VALUES ('"+category+"', '"+id+"', '"+name+"', '"+brand+"', '"+model+"', '"+quantity+"', '"+price+"')" );

    if( !myqry.exec() )
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Problem", "Failed to save the Data" + myqry.lastError());
    }
```

The error produced:

```
error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'const char [24]' and 'QSqlError')
         QMessageBox::information(this, "Problem", "Failed to save the Data" + myqry.lastError());
                                                                            ^
```

I've included the #include  in the header and cpp file as well and the same error reproduced once run qmake and run. I don't have idea what's the problem, could anyone help me on this ? The issue is with the operator +. :(

Comment: You probably meant `myqry.lastError().text()`. `myqry.lastError()` doesn't return a string, but an object describing various aspects of the error.

Comment: Hi @IgorTandetnik, thank you. It's working now. :)

Answer (score 1):

When working with `prepare` you better use it like this [(see Documentation)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/sql-sqlstatements.html#inserting-updating-and-deleting-records)

```
myqry.prepare("INSERT INTO Item (ItemCat, ItemId, ItemName, ItemBrand, ItemModel, ItemQuantity, ItemPrice) VALUES (:category, :id, :name, :brand, :model, :quantity, :price)");
myqry.bindValue(":category", category);
myqry.bindValue(":id", id);
myqry.bindValue(":name", name);
myqry.bindValue(":brand", brand);
myqry.bindValue(":model", model);
myqry.bindValue(":quantity", quantity);
myqry.bindValue(":price", price);

if(!myqry.exec())
{
 // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to concatenate literals with an object type (or a non-literal type).

You may use [std::to_string(value)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) to append non-string types to `string`'s, if your value is a primitive type.

Otherwise you should usually look for some `to_string()` method...

In particular, most `Qt` objects have a [text()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlerror.html#text) function.

---

If you check out the [QString documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#operator-2b-eq), you will see that the `+ operator` accepts only literals types, such as other `QString`'s, `const char*` and so on...